# How to change the database name and table using java?

Tags: java, mysql

i try to understand this part of code:

```
Properties details= new Properties();
details.load(new FileInputStream("details.properties"));
String userName = details.getProperty("root");
String password = details.getProperty("mysqlpassword");

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
System.out.println ("Database connection established");
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("insert into 'Email_list' values(?)");
for(String mail:mails)
```

i understand that test database is a default database. but if i want to use an existing database, i will just modify test to another database name isn't it?
If yes how do i modify my code if my new database is Test2 with table name Email which contains mail column with varchar(100)

i try to replace test by Test2  Email_list by Email but i don't know where to put the column name mail.
Thank you for help

Comment: I believe you are not getting `Database connection established` output... right?? this is because you are missing `PORT` number in your connection.... `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";` should be `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";`.. Here `3306` is PORT number...

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT` statement you use omits the columns.

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

can be written if the table has three columns and for all three columns values are provided.

If some columns can be left empty or have default values, you can write

```
INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2) VALUES (1, 2)
```

In this cas the value for `column3` is `null` or the default value.

So in your case the column name is put nowhere.

Comment: Can you please attach a tutorial link for the OP.

Comment: OK so i try this  PreparedStatement st= conn.prepareStatement("insert into 'mail' values(Email_list) values");

Comment: This will probably not work because `values()` contains the *values*, not the column names. Try to use the `mysql` client to work with your database directly. Come back to Java later.

Comment: OK so i try this  PreparedStatement st= conn.prepareStatement("insert into Email (mail) values (?)"; i have an error Cannot connect to the database and com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'Test2'

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `PORT` number in your connection string...

`String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";` should be `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/test";` like `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";`

Let me know if you have any queries...

Also, Check below how `Prepared Statement` works

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TwicePreparedStatement{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Twice use prepared statement example!\n");
  Connection con = null;
  PreparedStatement prest;
  try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:
//localhost:3306/jdbctutorial","root","root");
  try{
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year_made = ?";
  prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  prest.setInt(1,2002);
  ResultSet rs1 = prest.executeQuery();
  System.out.println("List of movies that made in year 2002");
  while (rs1.next()){
  String mov_name = rs1.getString(1);
  int mad_year = rs1.getInt(2);
  System.out.println(mov_name + "\t- " + mad_year);
  }
  prest.setInt(1,2003);
  ResultSet rs2 = prest.executeQuery();
  System.out.println("List of movies that made in year 2003");
  while (rs2.next()){
  String mov_name = rs2.getString(1);
  int mad_year = rs2.getInt(2);
  System.out.println(mov_name + "\t- " + mad_year);
  }
  }
  catch (SQLException s){
  System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
  }
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
}
```

Good Luck!!!